# Are complete lattices an axiomatizable class?

Tags: model-theory

Is the class of complete lattices a first-order axiomatizable class? Certainly, the class of lattices is. And if it is axiomatizable, is it finitely axiomatizable?

Comment: What is the definition of "first-order axiomatizable class"?  Are you asking whether there is a set $\Sigma$ of first-order sentences such that the class of all models of $\Sigma$ is the class of all complete lattices? If so, why is the question not immediately answered in the negative by the fact that some complete lattice is elementarily equivalent to some incomplete lattice, e.g., $\langle\mathbb R,\le\rangle\equiv\langle\mathbb Q,\le\rangle$?

Comment: Oops, by $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb Q$ I meant $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb Q\cap[0,1]$. Of course a complete lattice has a top and bottom element. Sorry about that. Just woke up.

Comment: @bof Yes, that is what I mean. Thanks for answering. Now, what is the proof that those lattices are elementarily equivalent?

Comment: Well, the complete lattice $[0,1]$ is elementarily equivalent to **some** countable lattice, which must be totally ordered, densely ordered, with least and greatest element, since those are first-order properties. All countable dense totally ordered sets with least and greatest elements are isomorphic (Cantor) as ordered sets and therefore as lattices. You could also show elementary equivalence more directly, e.g. with Fraisse-Ehrenfeucht games.

Comment: Alternately, apply downwards Lowenheim-Skolem to a complete atomistic lattice with infinitely many atoms - since the cardinality of a complete atomistic lattice is $2$ to the cardinality of its set of atoms, the result can't be complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the class of complete lattices is not axiomatizable because it is not closed under untrapowers.